# When i Add a firebase admin SDK after that I want to disable the user account I run the android project i show the error

Tags: android, firebase

Code:

```
holder.block.setText("Block");
               String  email=listdata.get(position).getShop_name();
                UserRecord.UpdateRequest request = new UserRecord.UpdateRequest(email)
                        .setDisabled(true);
```

Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.3.0 (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.3.0) and jetified-firebase-database-19.7.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0)

Comment: Please give me ans of my question I do my Final year project of my BSSE please guide me

Comment: My contact number is 03023788688